# Google Analytics - random Destination URLs creating 404 errors

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Sorry I don't post here often so sorry if I'm doing something wrong. I have a question about Analytics. I keep getting tonnes of searches for URLs that are bizarre and dont' exist. They look like this: 
/<____________@rom
/<____________pive

Etc....

It's creating a huge abundance of 404 hits against my site :( Anyone ever seen this before or know why it's happening? Or more importantly, how to do stop it?

[screenshot of destination URLs being targeted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ9Qp.jpg)

Comment: That looks a lot like a problem with the analytics code in your site. Could you post here how the analytics code is generated?

Comment: Seems like analytics spam, you could create filters to filter out invalid traffic

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I'm implementing Analytics through GTM. I created tag in Universal Analytics Tag and applied it to 'all pages'. The only 'snippet' you'll see on the site is for GTM. 

Filtering out the invalid traffic is a great idea, however, my concern is that I'm getting a tonne of 404 errors which I'm thinking for Google ranking is going to look really bad. 

Why is some robot trying to search for pages with the URL /<_______@rom etc. It's so super weird, no site would have a url like that. :( It would obviously return 404. The world makes no sense.